# Do I need to supply the branch node if I don't need the value in it in a Patricia tree?

Tags: ethereum, merkle-tree, patricia-trie

[image]

For example, in this PATRICIA tree, if I want to prove that the key 'fc' has no value mapped
to it, should I bring up the branch node stored the data value “b” even though I don't need the data value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I will use the branch anyway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).